# Indexing on Partition

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I deleted indexing on partioned table in Oracle.Is ther a way to recreate the index on the same??

Comment: yes, partitioned tables can be indexed, so there's no reason you couldn't. what specifically is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Deleting, do you mean "Dropped" an index on a partitioned table? You can always recreate them using one of the methods (based on your needs) shown here..

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/schemaob.htm#CNCPT1520
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/schemaob.htm#CNCPT1521